# Kivy app for android loads but then disappears

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build the clock application given in [Kivy Blueprints](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SYOBY2W) book with

- Architecture: x86_64
- OS: Linux Mint 5.0.0-32-generic
- Python: 3.8
- Kivy: 1.11.1
- Buildozer: 1.2.0
- main.py: https://github.com/mvasilkov/kb/blob/master/1_Clock/main.py
- clock.kv: https://github.com/mvasilkov/kb/blob/master/1_Clock/clock.kv

Code works perfectly on the PC however when I build .apk with buildozer (`buildozer -v android debug logcat > my_log.txt`) and run on Android device (Android 6.0 and 8.1), a splashscreen loads and then disappears.

You can see the log file here: https://justpaste.it/5ytij

Can anyone point the problem please?

UPDATE_1: As @inclement pointed out, I included only the build log from buildozer in the above message. I run `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt` this time. Android logs are here: https://justpaste.it/3sfmh

UPDATE_2: I was using OpenJDK-8. I detected some issues in the earlier log that might be related with the Java so I installed Oracle JDK-8 and used it. Android log is here: https://justpaste.it/7rvuw . If you take a look at it you can see crash logs like this;

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-04 20:19:40.292  8815  8833 F libc    : Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0xc0011 in tid 8833 (Compiler driver)
06-04 20:19:40.399  3815  3815 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-04 20:19:40.399  3815  3815 F DEBUG   : UUID: e445db0b-d8e5-4910-9240-ffbdc085519e
```

Can someone decipher those lines?

Thanks.

Comment: The `buildozer` documentation says to run `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt`. You have left out the `deploy run` part.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: What you've posted is the build log, you need the logcat log from Android.

Comment: I am using Kivy Launcher to test the code for now. I think I will try to build apk on another machine when it is ready.